# How can I get vi-like keybindings in other Mac applications/text entry fields than just Terminal?

Tags: macos, vi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to make all text fields in OS X editable with Vi keybindings?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43710/is-it-possible-to-make-all-text-fields-in-os-x-editable-with-vi-keybindings)

I use [vim](http://www.vim.org/) a lot, and like the keybindings. I'm aware that I can get vi-like keybindings in the shell in Terminal.app by adding the following to my `~/.inputrc`:

> set editing-mode vi

However, I'd like to have vi/vim keybindings in other OS X apps - ideally in every text entry fields across all apps. Is there is a practical way to achieve this?

I'm using OS X 10.8.